Search results not updating
I normally read SO by searching for recent unanswered questions in my tags list. This is the link I've bookmarked:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion%20answers%3a0%20closed%3ano

In the past the results will occasionally not change for 5-10 minutes, I assume it's due to caching search results somewhere.
But this afternoon the newest question it shows is 4 hours old. I don't think it's my browser cache, as the problem persists when I disable the cache by opening Developer Tools.
If I just go to the SO home page, I see all recently asked and modified questions. If I search for "Asked" I see questions that have been asked in the past few minutes. It highlights questions that are in my tags, and these questions are highlighted.
Update:
The problem seems to have cleared up somewhat in the last few minutes (around 2024-10-09 22:55 UTC). Search results are updating regularly.

are you sure there's actually a new question? even changing the search to include a date range doesn't give a more recent post. Surely there must be...

interesting. it's literally every search you perform... how has this not been noticed till now

I've updated the question. There are definitely questions in my tags that have been asked recently.

when i search "asked" from the home page, it sends me to most relevant which is all old stuff. if i select newest, i see 4 hours ago.

I suspect some kind of index got stuck 4 hours ago.

I wonder if it's related to we are reindexing all post titles network wide

I've asked over there.

We had to re-index our search docs yesterday, as folks have commented! You can read more about it here
It should be all done now!
